# Broken virtualenv but no succes with other solutions Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

When i tried to start django I get this:

```
(daxtest) MacBook-Pro-15-Officerebel:daxtest timvogt$ python manage.py runserver
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.python.org Installed new python 7 and issue was solved